# JPA banco de dados apenas leitura

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, mariadb, persistência

Bom dia, tenho um caso, atípico para mim.
Uma base de dados onde preciso fazer selects e update em 1 ou 2 colunas de uma tabela.
Gostaria de saber como configurar o meu persistence.xml

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="nfse" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.CancelamentoNfseV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.CompNfseV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.ConfirmacaoCancelamentoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.ContatoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.CpfCnpjV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.DadosConstrucaoCivilV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.DadosPrestadorV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.DadosServicoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.DadosTomadorV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.EnderecoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.IdentificacaoIntermediarioServicoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.IdentificacaoNfseV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.IdentificacaoOrgaoGeradorV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.IdentificacaoPrestadorV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.IdentificacaoRpsV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.IdentificacaoTomadorV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.InfConfirmacaoCancelamentoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.InfNfseV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.InfPedidoCancelamentoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.InfRpsV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.InfSubstituicaoNfseV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.ListaRpsV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.LoteRpsV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.MensagemRetornoLoteV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.MensagemRetornoLoteV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.MensagemRetornoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.NfseV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.PedidoCancelamentoV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.RpsV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.SubstituicaoNfseV3Vo</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.ValoresV3Vo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.150.3:3306/NFe"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="n9KN2T"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="source" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.NfeDados</class>
        <class>nfse.vo.nfse.vo.NfeClientes</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.150.2:3306/meubanco"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="nfe"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="r5NvjZR"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso você pode realizar a modificação na entidade ou no banco de dados.

No **JAVA** adicione a anotação `@Column` com o atributo de `insertable = false` caso queira impedir inserts e `updatable = false` para não permitir atualizações:

```
@Column(name="coluna", updatable=false, insertable=false)
private Object coluna;
```

No **banco**, modifique a permissão de um usuário para tabelas você pode usar o seguinte comando:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON nome_do_banco.nome_da_tabela TO 'usuario'@'localhost';
```

Para restringir o usuário de criar ou apagar registros modifique o comando para:

```
 GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON nome_do_banco.nome_da_tabela TO 'usuario'@'localhost';
```

Para outra situação basta alterar o comando de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Comment: tenho esse erro: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: CREATE command denied to user 'dgnetwork-nfe'@'10.0.0.55' for table 'hibernate_sequence'

Comment: Não posso criar absolutamente nada nessa base

Comment: @willianrodriguesandrade, esse erro ocorreu quando você fez o que? Posta o seu `persistence.xml`

Comment: Editei a pergunta e postei o persistence.xml

Comment: retira essa linha `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>` do persistence unit `source`